# Copy the last modified Dir from one location to another using Perl

Tags: perl

fairly new to perl so this is most likely is not the best code which is why I am posting.  I got this to work but was wondering if there is a better way.  I do not have the ability to download modules. I am copying the last modified directory in a build folder from one server to another server.  The argument allows me to choose which build directory to choose from.
Thanks

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy::Recursive;

my $NewFolder = `(dir /o-d/ad/b \\\\myserver1.name.com\\builds\\$ARGV[0] | head -1)`;
chomp($NewFolder);

 $dir1 = "\\\\myserver1.name.com\\builds\\$ARGV[0]/$NewFolder";
 $dir2 = "\\\\myserver2.name.com\\builds\\$ARGV[0]/Backup/$NewFolder";


File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy $dir1, $dir2 or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forward slashes. It just makes your code easier to read:

```
$dir1 = "\\\\myserver1.name.com\\builds\\$ARGV[0]/$NewFolder";
```

vs.

```
$dir1 = "//myserver1.name.com/builds/$ARGV[0]/$NewFolder";
```

Also, don't do system calls where Perl can do it. For example, Perl can see the last modification date of a file via the [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html). Even better is the [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) module that makes the `stat` command so much easier to use.

Don't use `@ARGV` in your programs. Instead, read the variables from `@ARGV` into your own variables. It makes your program easier to understand, and your own variables have limited scope while `@ARGV` is global.

Use *modern* conventions. Variable names should be in all lower case, and use underscores to separate out words. That is `$new_folder` vs. `$NewFolder`. Is this arbitrary? Yes, but it's a convention followed by most Perl developers. It means not wondering if the variable is `$newFolder`, `$NewFolder`, or `$newfolder` because you know by these rules it is `$new_folder`.

And finally, `use autodie;` This will kill your program whenever a file operation fails. This turns perl from a *check function for errors* programming language into a *exception checking language*. This way, you don't have to worry whether or not you have to check for a failed IO operation.

Here's a completely untested, error ridden example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy); #Optional Module
use File::Stat;

use constants {
    ORIG_SERVER => '//myserver1.name.com/builds',
    TO_SERVER   => '//myserver2.name.com/builds',
};

my $from_directory = shift;

#
# Find newest directory
#
opendir my $dir_fh, ORIG_SERVER . "/$from_directory";
my $newest_directory;

while ( my $sub_directory = readdir $dir_fh ) {
    next if $sub_directory eq "." or $sub_directory eq "..";
    next unless -d $sub_directory;

    if ( not defined $newest_directory ) {
        $youngest_directory = $sub_directory;
        next;
    }

    my $youngest_directory_stat = stat ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$newest_directory";
    my $sub_directory_stat = stat ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$sub_directory";
    if ( $newest_directory_stat->mtime > $sub_directory_stat->mtime ) {
       $newest_directory = $sub_directory;
    }
}

dircopy ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$youngest_directory",
    TO_SERVER . "/$directory/$youngest_directory/backup";
```

My program is a lot longer than your program because your program depended upon various system operating commands, like `dir` and `head` which I don't believe is a standard Windows OS command. Instead, I read each entry under that directory into my loop. Anything that's not a directory, I toss (`next if -d $sub_directory`) and I toss out the special directories `.` and `..`.

After that, I use `stat` to find the youngest directory which to me means the one with the newest *modification time*. Note that Unix doesn't store *creation time*. However, according to [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) `ctime` is creation time on Win32, so you might prefer that instead of `mtime`.

If I didn't use `File::stat`, instead of this:

```
my $youngest_directory_stat = stat ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$newest_directory";
my $sub_directory_stat = stat ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$sub_directory";
if ( $newest_directory_stat->mtime > $sub_directory_stat->mtime ) {
   $newest_directory = $sub_directory;
}
```

I could have done this:

```
my $newest = ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$newest_directory";
my $sub_dir = ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$sub_directory";
if ( stat( $newest )[9] > stat( $sub_dir )[9] ) {
   $newest_directory = $sub_directory;
}
```

The `stat` command without `File::stat` returns an array of values, and I could have simply used the `[9]` element of that array. However, what is 9? Even though it could of saved me a few lines of code, and including an extra Perl module, it's better to use `File::stat`.

One thing you notice is that constants don't interpolate which means I have to keep doing things like this:

```
my $youngest_directory_stat = stat ORIG_SERVER . "/$directory/$newest_directory";
```

However, you can use this bit of Perlish black magic to interpolate constants inside quotes:

```
my $youngest_directory_stat = stat "@{[ORIG_SERVER]}/$directory/$newest_directory";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, David.  Yes that helps very much.  Really appreciate your time.  I have a lot to take away from your post.  I am going through the pieces and looking different parts up.  A bit difficult here to express my gratitude but just want to try and express how helpfull your post is.